# Example of dense subset in topological space that does not have a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We just went over the Zariski topology in my algebraic geometry class and we see the zero ideal is dense in $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$. This made me realize that I cant think of any other good examples of a dense subset in a topological space that isnt just a metric space. Does anyone have any good examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, on $\Bbb R$ consider the topology$$\tau=\{\emptyset,\Bbb R\}\cup\{(-\infty,a)\mid a\in\Bbb R\}.$$Then $\Bbb Z$ is dense on $(\Bbb R,\tau)$. Actually, every subset of $\Bbb R$ without an upper bound is dense in $(\Bbb R,\tau)$.

Comment: great example. this helps me think of lots more since this one is easy to visualize.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious example would be any non empty subspace of a space with the trivial topology, or any infinite set in a space with the finite complement topology.

An example with more separation axioms would be the successor ordinals in the first uncountable ordinal with the order topology.

As a last example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in the sorgenfrey line, which is not metrizable.